# How to solve separate questions in iOS without warning?

Tags: ios, warnings

The following code does work, but it still makes me frustated because in the `else` block the deprecated method call leads to a warning.

```
if ([self.navigationController respondsToSelector:@selector(dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:)])
{
    [self.navigationController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
else
{
    //Here,the warning goes!
    //dismissModalViewControllerAnimated is deprecated
    [self.navigationController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

How can I hide the warning dismissed, or is there any other way to solve the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can temporarily disable deprecation warnings around the line of code in question:

```
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wdeprecated-declarations"

[self.navigationController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

#pragma clang diagnostic pop
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any reason for keeping both dismissViewControllerAnimated & dismissModalViewControllerAnimated. You are getting warning for dismissModalViewControllerAnimated because deployment target for your project is 6.0 and dismissModalViewControllerAnimated  is deprecated in iOS 6 SDK.

1. If you want your app to support to iOS below 6.0, change deployment target to below 6.0(e.g. 5.0) and use only dismissModalViewControllerAnimated for dismissing modals.
2. If you want your app to support iOS 6.0+, then keep deployment target as 6.0 and use only dismissViewControllerAnimated for dismissing presented controllers.

Comment: Thank you.But I want my app support iOS 4.3 above including iOS 6.0 at the same time .Not only for iOS below 6.0 or iOS 6.0+.

Comment: But, I think dismissModalViewControllerAnimated works in iOS 6.0 even if deployment target is below 6.0